# How to CheckConstraint in about the same way it is done on database server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, ms-access

I am working on dynamically generating data that parses database constraint checks using either C++, C# or even Java. I am currently working on the design for the application, and would appreciate tips on how this could be done in code.

What I would like to is query the database for the information on a table, when I get that information back, for each CheckConstraint, what I would like to do is, in code, parse that constraint, and somehow generate data that complies with the constraint. This I want to be able to do for any Database specified by the USER. Given that I am trying to stick to ANSI SQL standards, I figure this method should work for any Database that complies.

And this is for any database really since data  generation is not limited to SQL Server.

Comment: why did you tag this with MySQL, Oracle and MS-Access? It seems you are only concerned about SQL Server?

Comment: NO, I am not only concerned with SQLServer Database but all databases out that I can get this to work for. I only have a link up there to the MS CheckClause for SQL Server to give an example.

Comment: MySQL and MS Access do not support check constraints.

Comment: Not according to this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html, in the case of MySQL

Comment: Also for Access, there is this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/201888

Comment: Thanks for the update on MS Access, I wasn't aware of that. But MySQL accepts the syntax, but ignores it. If you read the whole chapter from your link you'll see the sentence: "*The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines*"

Comment: Yeah but what I want to do is a generator that still is able to get that information from MYSQL, parse it, and generate data specific to what the user really wants.

Comment: You can't. MySQL doesn't store that information because it ignores it.

Comment: Well, in the case that I am able to get access to it, from any of the other databases, I would like to be able to parse that information and essentially generate data to the specification.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, JET can consume some constraint commands.

Eg:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers 
   (CustId IDENTITY (100, 10), 
   CFrstNm VARCHAR(10), 
   CLstNm VARCHAR(15),
   CustomerLimit DOUBLE,

   CHECK (CustomerLimit <= (SELECT SUM (CreditLimit) FROM CreditLimit)))
```

So in above, the customer limit cannot exceed the credit limit.

As the end of the day, I not sure where the poster is going with this since EVERY single database vendor not only has different features, functions, but the relational integrity features are different and so is the relational integrity syntax for setting up such relations and options like delete restrict

As noted, in addition to RI features in Access (and some via sql DDL commands), then we have check constraint syntax (again via sql DDL commands), we ALSO now have store procedure code.

And AGAIN such syntax is different feature wise and ALSO syntax wise.

So for Access 2010 and the new data engine ACE, we  have the choice of table triggers and store procedures. So you can write procedural code to check conditions and if you raise an error in the before change table trigger then the update will not occur. So store procedures in before change event is also another way to achieve conditional testing for preventing record updates. However once again such store procedure code is vendor specific just like it is for pl/sql, T-SQL, or .

So the real challenge here is that the syntax and language of the store procedure code is DIFFERENT IN EACH case for EACH system.

So in Access you can use some DDL commands for "check" constraints, you can also have some RI features (delete restrict, cascade delete, FK cascade update). And last but not least you can also now write some table trigger code for Access 2010, (and the new ACE data engine).

At the end of the day the real problem in many cases is not so much the difference in features, but the worse part of not a common adoption of standards for such said features.

Comment: Maybe My question is not that clear. I should try to rephrase.